# How to determine if I need a new TCP connection from a Rust io::Error?

Tags: tcp, error-handling, redis, io, rust

I'm using the [redis crate](https://docs.rs/redis/0.12.0/redis/) to talk to a Redis server over TCP from Rust. If the TCP connection for some reason goes down (e.g. server crash), I want to try to reconnect (with some backoff so as not to clog the server) by creating a new [`Connection`](https://docs.rs/redis/0.12.0/redis/struct.Connection.html).

My problem is how to determine when to reconnect? The redis crate throws [`RedisError`](https://docs.rs/redis/0.12.0/redis/struct.RedisError.html)'s, and some of these contain an [`io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.kind). How do I determine which `io::Error`'s require a new connection, and which don't? I guess I will have to match on [`io::Error::kind()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.kind) along the lines of this:

```
use std::io;

fn needs_new_connection(error: &io::Error) -> bool {
    match error.kind() {
        io::ErrorKind::ConnectionReset |
        io::ErrorKind::ConnectionAborted => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

But what [`ErrorKind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html)'s should be in there? Should I add `NotConnected`? `TimedOut`? Others? Or should I use some completely different approach?

While I am using Redis, I think it should be fine to treat this as a question purely about TCP. I'm not supporting Unix sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be working off the `RedisError` itself to figure out what happened and if you need to reconnect. There are a bunch of useful methods defined on that type to help you figure out what you need to do:

- `is_io_error()` will return `true` if the error was due to I/O, and `is_timeout()` will return `true` if the cause was I/O timeout
- `is_connection_dropped()` returns `true` if your connection was dropped
- `is_connection_refusal()` returns `true` if your connection was actively refused (or if the server flat-out does not exist)

These methods will allow you to pinpoint which type of connection error it was without having to enumerate every possible variant. In particular, to cover most cases, you'll be interested in combining them. In this situation, I'd honestly go `(error.is_io_error() || error.is_connection_dropped()) && !error.is_connection_refusal()`. That covers every accidental I/O failure case, while making sure to avoid cases such as invalid credentials.

Comment: I think this would include `io::ErrorKind::TimedOut` (since it `is_io_error()` but not `is_connection_refusal()`). Is that the correct way to deal with time outs? I have no idea... :-)

Comment: `TimedOut` is considered an [IO error](https://mitsuhiko.github.io/redis-rs/src/redis/types.rs.html#274) and one of the cases you should re-attempt.